# Is there AWS solution to sort out SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, architecture, event-handling, amazon-sqs

I have this architectural dilemma, and thought, maybe this is solved problem, or solvable multiple ways. I've got an SQS queue (one of many), which is triggering a Lambda function (one of many). This queue requires slightly different processing of messages, based on one key in the payload. What would be the best way for sorting out the queue messages before actual processing by Lambda?

Should it be separate Lambda, which will check for the key, and then place the message into separate queue, which will trigger corresponding Lambda?

Should it be just bunch of if statements in primary Lambda?

Is there maybe automated way to deal with such situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that there are different types of messages in the Amazon SQS queue, which need processing by different Lambda functions? How many different types? What is preventing the different types of messages from being processed by a single Lambda function (eg is it totally different code)? Can you modify whatever process that is sending messages to the SQS queue to send them to different queues, based on this 'key'?

Comment: Messages are of a different sub-type, let's put it this way. There is SNS topic, which this queue is subscribed to, and this topic is not under my control. Messages should be processed in a slightly different manner, yes. 
Differences are not drastic, that's why I could just place a switch case inside my lambda, and this will do the job. But I am wondering, if there is more elegant solution for such a situation. Considering, that differences might grow, new sub-types added, and the need to distinguish sub-types will grow as well (for example, for monitoring purposes)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your situation is:

- An external process sends messages to an **Amazon SNS topic**
- An **Amazon SQS queue** is subscribed to the SNS topic
- An **AWS Lambda function** is subscribed to the SQS queue
- There are **various sub-types of messages**, each of which should be processed slightly differently

One option is to use [Amazon SNS Message Filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html), which can deliver messages differently based upon a **message attribute**. It could, for example, send a subset of messages to an SNS topic or Lambda function. However, this would require the messages being sent to the SNS topic to **have a message attribute defined**.

If this is not the case, then possible options are:

- Use one Lambda function to **process all message types** (You can include quite complex code in multiple files within a Lambda function!), *or*
- Use a Lambda function to **determine the message sub-type and then send it to a specific Lambda function** (or, send it via an SQS queue to a Lambda function for added resiliency)

Comment: yes, that's pretty much what I have figured so far. thanks